# Best way to implement try catch in php4

Tags: error-handling, try-catch, php4

What is the closest you can get to a try-catch block in php4?

I'm in the middle of a callback during an xmlrpc request and it's required to return a specifically structured array no matter what.

I have to error check all accesses to external resources, resulting in a deep stack of nested if-else blocks, ugly.

Comment: If you're writing new code, write it for PHP5. There is no try/catch (exception) in PHP4.

Comment: Maybe you should upvote the answer if you think it's worth of being "the answer"

Comment: almost 8 years later, and I'm dealing with the same issue. I can't believe the company I'm working for has left this system as PHP 4 for so long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Late answer, I realise, sorry. I hope this is still relevant for you:

First, I'm echoing the comments your got in response to your post. PHP5 is the way to go.

However:

> I'm in the middle of a callback during
>   an xmlrpc request and it's required to
>   return a specifically structured array
>   no matter what.

If you can vouch for that the program cannot possibly continue without getting a structured array back, and you absolutely have to work with PHP4, then an **exit()** or **die()** with detailed error information will get you much the same effect as a fatal exception would.

That's far removed from being graceful, of course. If you want something catchable, then return values and if-checking the result are your best bet, unfortunately. There are some standard ways of passing back specific error objects, but it's still the same thing - return the error object, if-check whether the result was an error object, react.

Still, take a look at [PEAR's error object](http://pear.activeventure.com/core/core.pear.pear.intro.html).